# Best way to make a hole in concrete wall

Tags: concrete, walls, vent, drill, hole

So my house has concrete walls and ceilings. There a few places i would need to remove some large holes like for vents or light fixtures. I was looking at a concrete hole saw which seems to be a good idea but im not sure it would last or what kind of drill to attach it too. Any ideas.

Comment: Do you know how thick the concrete is and if there is any rebar in it?

Comment: maybe 6 inches at the thickest and yes there is rebar in it

Comment: also make sure none of it is pre-stressed concrete.

Comment: I don't understand the issue of rebar.  You should try to work around the rebar not go through it.  Are you saying your wall has solid rebar sheets?

Comment: No just rebar bars. Id wanna make a hole straight through the wall and im gonna hit rebar bars

Answer (score 1):

Menards and other places rent core drills for large holes in concrete.

Easiest way is to call Diamond Drilling or a similar company and have them come out and drill all your holes for a few hundred dollars.

Unless you want to buy a Hilti DD100 and the bits which will cost you way more than hundreds.

Edit: Sorry I just re-read your post. If you want to cut bigger holes then you need diamond concrete saw blades for a standard circular saw. They will wear down so you could start with 1 or 2 and see how far that gets you. Depends on how many holes you want to make. Hopefully they are available in Ecuador.

Or you could order one like [this](http://www.zoro.com/diamond-vantage-diamond-saw-blade-masonry-12-in-dia-1212esi/i/G4921971/?gdffi=047ada998cf641fa93e55ae8579df863&gdfms=1C9560CCBBBE4890B410F64A88B0EF66&gclid=CjwKEAiAluG1BRDrvsqCtYWk81gSJACZ2BCezYnnLy-irb1LV-hMPDGCfa1ODSNorUkOoZCPTG9zkxoCa0_w_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Then you will need a sledgehammer, wedges, chisels, and lots of muscle.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the answer but this is for a house in Ecuador.

Answer (score 0):

If you're drilling into concrete you'll need an hammer drill and some impact bits.  For a hole larger than 1" I'd probably use some sort of air hammer to chisel through the concrete.  If you come across rebar you could chisel around it and then cut it out with a hacksaw blade.

Comment: would something like this not work? http://www.amazon.com/inch-concrete-diamond-hole-saw/dp/B00ENA3X84

Comment: @Learner Not if there is rebar.  That is made for drilling tile or stone, not reinforced concrete.

Comment: couldnt i just use it half way, cut the rebar with an angle grinder and then continue with the saw? Though i have some questions about angle grinders maybe for a latter question

Comment: Do you mean a Hammer drill and Hammer bits? Neither an impact wrench or impact driver will be any use going through concrete.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Why wouldn't the hole saw work on concrete with rebar?  Steel rebar is way softer than the porcelain this thing says it can cut.  Now, this hole saw also requires a pretty hefty drill driver to drive it, plus I think it says it's for wet cutting......

Comment: what kind of drill would you need

Comment: Yes, a hammer drill is what I am talking about.  An impact driver would be pretty useless.

Answer (score 0):

The diamond core drilling bits like you linked will go through concrete and rebar, but it will need water to go through rebar.  The rebar will heat up the bit and ruin the diamond without water cooling.

They are made for use with a special drill, a core drilling rig, which usually has a 5/8" threaded attachment (like a grinder) rather than a chuck like a drill.  It's not a simple setup or procedure.  The equipment and the bits are expensive.

I wish I knew and easy way to get through concrete with rebar, but I don't think there is one.  These core rigs sell because they're what work, if there was an easier way they wouldn't make them!